# How to sort the strings and insert into sql table in JAVA

Tags: java

In an excel sheet, i have 2 columns (first is the parent and second is child) like

> ```
> Parent    Child
> ```
>
> ---

```
BHW       HLF
BHW       Instr
BHW       Interior
BHW       Exterior
BR        BRF
BR        CR
BR        Panel
BR        Frame
BR        Paint
BR        Plastic
```

Both the parent columns and child columns will get inserted into a sql table. I am inserting all the parent columns first (only parent per set) When the child column gets inserted, the Parent_id column in the table will have the parent value of it.

1. I am unable to sort the parent columns using Set . It returns first BR and then BHW.
2. if I dont remove duplicates and insert it, how can I match child wiht the parent and insert into the table.

Edit : My code :

```
import java.io.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;


import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;

public class ProdTable {

    String strBasePath = "D:\\Project\\Temp.xlsx";


    ArrayList<String>  arrListLevel_1_SCT       = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String>  arrListLevel_2_SC        = new ArrayList<String>();
    Set<String>        setUnqProducts           = new HashSet<String>();
    ArrayList<String>  arrListLevel_1_Unique    = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String>  strInsertQuery           = new ArrayList<String>();

    int iRowCount = 0;
    String strSheetName = "Sheet1";
    String strDBName = "ProductsDB";
    int intID = 0;
    int intRG_ID = 0;
    int intWG_ID = 0;
    int intRowIncrement = 1;

    int intInstQuery;

    public ProdTable()
    {

    }
    public void ProdInsert()
    {
        try{

        // Fetched out the data in excel to the arrListLevel_1_SCT and arrListLevel_2_SC

        System.out.println("arrListLevel_1_SCT = " +  arrListLevel_1_SCT.size());
        System.out.println("arrListLevel_2_SC = " +  arrListLevel_2_SC.size());

        // Finding duplicates - Exclusive list of the distinct Products
        setUnqProducts = findDuplicates(arrListLevel_1_SCT);
        arrListLevel_1_Unique.addAll(setUnqProducts);
        System.out.println("arrListLevel_1_Unique = " +  arrListLevel_1_Unique.size());

        // Connection for SQL Server.
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver").newInstance();
        // DFFST
         String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://DFFST:1433;DatabaseName=" + strDBName + ";" +
               "User=sa;Password=sa;";  

        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
        ResultSet generatedKeys = null; 
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;

        if (conn != null) {                 
            System.out.println("Connection Successful!");             
        } 

        //Create a Statement object
        Statement sql_stmt = conn.createStatement();

         //Create a Statement object
        Statement sql_stmt_1 = conn.createStatement();

        //Result Set for Prouduct Table
        ResultSet rs  = sql_stmt.executeQuery("SELECT MAX(ID), MAX(RG_ID), MAX(WG_ID) FROM " + strDBName + ".[dbo].Product");

        if ( rs.next() ) {     
            // Retrieve the auto generated key(s).     
            intID = rs.getInt(1); 
            intRG_ID = rs.getInt(2); 
            intWG_ID = rs.getInt(3); 
        }

        for (int iCount = 0 ;iCount < arrListLevel_1_Unique.size(); iCount++)
        {

         //Result Set for Prouduct Table


        sql_stmt_1.executeUpdate("\n IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM " + strDBName + ".[dbo].Product WHERE [Name] NOT LIKE '" + arrListLevel_1_Unique.get(iCount) + "') "
                + "\nINSERT INTO " + strDBName + ".[dbo].Product ([Name] ,"
                + "[RG_ID],[WG_ID],[Parent_Product]) "
                + "VALUES ( '" + arrListLevel_1_Unique.get(iCount) + "',"
                + + (intWG_ID + intRowIncrement) + ", " + (intWG_ID + intRowIncrement + 1) + ", 5828)");


        intRowIncrement++ ;
        }

    rs.close();
        sql_stmt.close();
        sql_stmt_1.close();


        //Close the database connection
        conn.close();
        }
        catch(Exception E)
       {
            E.printStackTrace(); 
        }

    }

public static Set findDuplicates(ArrayList<String> inpArrayList){
Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();

for(int i=0; i < inpArrayList.size(); i++){

    if(!set.contains(inpArrayList.get(i)))
    {
        set.add(inpArrayList.get(i));
    } 
}
 return set;
```

}

}

Please help me.
Thanks
Ramm

Comment: For 1.) do you mean `SortedSet`?  For an implementation of `SortedSet` you can use `TreeSet`.

Comment: I edited my question and added my code. Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use a [`TreeSet`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) and implement a custom `Comparator` with the ordering that you need.

Comment: I tried multiple ways, but it always returned the Parent elements not in the order which i gave. Like if the order is AA, AA, BB, BB, CC, DD, it shall give AA, BB,CC, DD . It gives in the jumbled order.